# How to get version of Elasticsearch server using NEST client?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I check against which version of Elasticsearch server I'm executing queries from .NET NEST client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IRootNodeInfoResponse` contains data about the version of Elasticsearch server, it can be fetched using `ElasticClient` instance:

```cs
    var rootNodeInfo = await elasticClient.RootNodeInfoAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(rootNodeInfo.Version.Number);
```

Prints, for example:

> 6.2.2